# URL rewrite - append subdomain for specific port

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to figure out the best way to use mod_rewrite to change a URL from:

http://localhost:8081

to:

http://localhost:8081/subdomain

I only want it to re-direct if it matches that specific port number.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerName host.domain.com
    RewriteEngine     On
    RewriteRule       ^(.*)$        http://host.domain.com:8081/subdomain/$1  [P]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: sometimes mod-rewrite is not needed, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/avoid.html, for a simpel redirection a Redirect instruction on this VirtualHost would be even simplier.